# error undefined method `group_values' in active_admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I try to implements active_admin in my app, and i'm follow this tutorial :

```
http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html
```

But when i'm execute this command in my console :

```
rails generate active_admin:resource product
```

The file successfully generate :

```
app/admin/product.rb
```

But when i'm access index product page in active_admin i get error like this :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `group_values' for #<Array:0xcfe093c>)
```

how to fix this? thanks before

Comment: what you have written in product.rb ???

Comment: why you asking about product.rb? i guess activeadmin not include more setting in product.rb

Comment: I am asking to figure out the issue. if you have override any thing in product.rb

Comment: ok, in my product.rb i'm not yet change anything

Comment: ok. What you have written in product model

Comment: class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  attr_accessible :name, :slug

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `admin/product.rb` you can put this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product, :as => "All Product" do

end
```

Hopefully, this will help.